# Button Notifications In Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have searched many forums and many web sites but i didn't find the required solution.**I had a requirement to show the number of notifications to buttons** .When the form Loads.If the notifications are hundred there should be 100 beside the button.if nothing  then no notification should be visible.

Please suggest me the required solution..

Thanks In advance.

They are asking the **similar functionality as in Icons of IOS4**.

Comment: You want to change a button caption to show a number? `MyButton.Caption := IntToStr(NotificationCount)`. Call this from `OnCreate`, for example.

Comment: Thanks David..My requirement is not to change the caption.It should be some thing like a image .Caption should be same.It should notify the user.

Comment: Use a TSpeedButton or a TBitBtn I think (sorry, memory weak today).  They can take icons. In modern Delphi, TButton does so and handles alpha nicely.

Comment: You are right David....But there requirement is like this ..please see link once...http://www.flickr.com/photos/simplified/4724166573/

Comment: Why don't you put an image like that in the question? As it happens I've absolutely no idea what things look like in iOS. An image makes it clear what you want.

Comment: -1 until the question is re-written so it makes sense.

Comment: May it be a default TButton or TBitBtn? Or does it have to be like an iOS button with large border radius?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using a component for this instead of making your own, there is one that does what you need. It will display a status and looks just like what you have shown in your image link.

[image]

You can see this page [here](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advsmoothbutton.asp)

It is not free though.

Comment: May i know about that component...?

Comment: @rakesh follow the link in the answer

Comment: It would take a lot of time and work to homebrew something that nice. +1.

Comment: @Chris: Well, in my experience, TMS controls have a tendency to be buggy and flicker. Of course, that you cannot see in the screenshot above...

Comment: Is this still free with Delphi XE?  I think it might be.  http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/28271

Comment: @Andreas: Alot of the flickering problems have been solved in later versions. I have the Component Pack, the support is excellent but the documentation is not.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 4 there are icons with notifications (for programm-startup) and no buttons (I think), so this is not really the same,... but maybe you can create a custom button (inherit from TButton) and use something like an onPaint Event (sorry this is too much dotnet-style,... don't know how it is called in delphi) to draw this "notification" to the button like you do it in TCanvas.

Comment: Thank you Daniel...I think this might be helpful.I will try it.meanwhile if you find any solution inform me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `TBalloonHint` component. For example, To show the notification,

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  point : TPoint;
begin
  point.X := sb1.Left;
  point.Y := sb1.Top;
  BalloonHint1.Delay := 100;
  //BalloonHint1.Description := 'This is your Notification!';
  BalloonHint1.HideAfter := -1;
  BalloonHint1.Style := bhsBalloon;
  BalloonHint1.Title := '2';
  sb1.ParentShowHint := False;
  BalloonHint1.ShowHint(point);
end;
```

To Hide the notification

```
procedure TForm1.sb1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BalloonHint1.HideHint;
end;
```

It would be see like the above image
[image]

If you want to show images, you can use the `BalloonHint1.Images` property.

Comment: Is this component available in Delphi 7 ..?

Answer (score -1):

You could use a TPaintBox and draw directly to its Canvas property.  TCanvas has a number of methods that would make this a fairly simple task, in my opinion.  Just store the background image separately (maybe in a TImage), copy it to the canvas (using the Draw method in the OnPaint event), and then paint the circle (Ellipse method) and the number last (TextOut or TextRect).  You can also use the OnClick event of the TPaintBox to manage the "button clicking" operations.

Comment: -1. This seems like a very bad idea. If you want to make your own button, then, of course, you should create your own control class deriving from `TCustomControl`.

Comment: But it is "similar functionality as in Icons of IOS4"... and on the cheap.  Best idea?  No.  Bad idea?  Depends on the circumstances.

Comment: @Jerry You don't make controls out of a paint box. Andreas is quite right. You can make them out of a proper control class and paint on a canvas in just the same way as on a paint box. But you get a real control.